# Hadoop error in namenode formating

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new to hadoop and I was trying basic hadoop installation in ubuntu. After setting up everything, I got an error while formating HDFS system and when I run it, it shows the following error...

error

```
    hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ hadoop namenode -format
-su: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Permission denied
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ ls -ltr
total 116
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1168 Jul 23 03:56 stop-mapred.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1131 Jul 23 03:56 stop-jobhistoryserver.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1246 Jul 23 03:56 stop-dfs.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1116 Jul 23 03:56 stop-balancer.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1119 Jul 23 03:56 stop-all.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1259 Jul 23 03:56 start-mapred.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1145 Jul 23 03:56 start-jobhistoryserver.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1745 Jul 23 03:56 start-dfs.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1065 Jul 23 03:56 start-balancer.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1166 Jul 23 03:56 start-all.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  2050 Jul 23 03:56 slaves.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  2810 Jul 23 03:56 rcc
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  1329 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-daemons.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  5064 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-daemon.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop  2643 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop-config.sh
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop 15147 Jul 23 03:56 hadoop
-rw------- 1 hduser hadoop 63598 Jul 23 03:57 task-controller
```

Eagerly waiting for reply
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-su: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Permission denied**

You do not have proper permissions. You need execute permissions on these files in order to proceed. You should be good to go once that's done.

Answer (score 1):

As user don't have the *execute permission* so fire the below command. It's worked for me.

**sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop/bin/***